# Returning Item That Can't Be Divided By Zero

Tags: java, methods

On my current assignment I've created a class that will print a few statistics on baseball players. Right now, I'm having issues with ensuring that the calcBattingAverage is not divisible by zero. Once I pair that and run my test class, I get an "ArithmeticException: / by zero error". Here is what I've attempted so far:

```
 public double calcBattingAverage(){

   double battingAverage;
   battingAverage=hits/atBats;

   if (battingAverage == 0){
   }

   return battingAverage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that atBats isn't == 0 before using it in division.

```
double battingAverage = 0.0;
if (atBats > 0) {
    battingAverage = (double)hits/atBats;
}
```

Otherwise anytime you have no atBats, you'll get the division by 0 error.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately when I do this and I run the test, every batting average prints as "0.0". I noticed that one player has their average left blank. That would return -1. Would that affect this outcome?

Comment: Do your players have at bats? If they are all 0, then your averages are going to be all 0. Trying printing out at bats at the top of your function and make sure the data is correct.

Comment: Only one player does not have an atBat currently.

Comment: It might be that your hits are 0, or that both atbats and hits are integers, in which case you'll need to convert one too a double IE: battingAverage = (double)hits/atBats

Comment: Ah yes. That makes sense. Currently one player doesn't have any hits or bats and is left out. The other two have both hits and atBats.

Comment: BOOM! That was correct. Thank you so much for taking the time out of your day to assist me with the issue. It was converting the integer values to double. Everything is set. Thanks again.